# Developer story link and icon not line breaking together

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, developer-story

The GitHub icon on [my developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/story/austinallman) is not line breaking with the link.

[image: Icon not breaking with link]

Comment: +1 for freehand cir-- hey, wait! That's not a full circle! No +1 for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There was no real connection between the icon and the text on the page, so each wrapped independently.  I was just going to just stick it in a `<div style="display: inline-block">` but the designer gave it the full treatment, adopting some existing flex box styles and moving the icons over to SVG.  So in addition to wrapping correctly, the icons will now highlight with the text on mouse over and print better, and I think there's probably a 5px alignment fix in there too. :)